# How can I remove my response from a recurring Facebook event? How to undo "interested" for ALL of the occurances?

Tags: facebook, facebook-events

After I clicked "interested" to a recurring event, I noticed that the location is very far, making it extremely unlikely that I would ever attend.

I unselected "interested" for the first couple, but I don't have the patience to do that 100 times.

Now I keep getting reminders, and every time I unselect "interested" for a couple occurrences.

Is there a way to completely remove myself from all the occurrences of this event? Or just stop getting notifications for this event?